# Removing duplicates in a char[] O(n)

Tags: java, algorithm

We're given a `char[]` containing characters `A-Z`. (For more characters this can easily be extended). Now we're asked to remove all duplicates in the `char[]`.

For example, in: \$['B','A','A']\$, out \$['B','A']\$.

The algorithm:

```
public void removeDuplicates(final char[] s) {
  if (s == null || s.length < 2) {
    return;
  }

  int checker = 0;
  int j = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    if ((checker & 1 << s[i] - 'A') == 0) {
      s[j] = s[i];
      j++;
      checker |= 1 << s[i] - 'A';
    }
  }

  while (j < s.length) {
    s[j] = 0;
    j++;
  }
}
```

Here, `checker` is an `int` whose bits represent whether we've seen a character before. For example, if we've seen `A` and `C`, `checker` would be 5 (`101`).

`i` is our next character to check, and for \$j > 0\$, \$[s[0], s[1], ... , s[j-1]]\$ contains no duplicate characters.

Worst case: \$2n-1 = O(n)\$

Test cases:

- `null` -> `null`
- `[]` -> `[]`
- `['A']` -> `['A']`
- `['A','B']` -> `['A','B']`
- `['A','A']` -> `['A']`
- `['B','A','A']` -> `['B','A']`
- `['A','B','C','D']` -> `['A','B','C','D']`
- `['A','B','A','D']` -> `['A','B','D']`
- `['A','B','A','D','D','A']` -> `['A','B','D']`

I am looking for any flaws, mistakes and opinions in general.

Comment: I'd add a few redundant parentheses so it doesn't rely on operator precedence that much.

Comment: Is this code performance critical? If performance isn't that essential, I'd rather use a high level Set type instead of a custom bitfield.

Comment: @CodesInChaos In my original handwritten draft, I indeed included them. Since my IDE complained they weren't necessary, I removed them. Would you include all the parentheses, like `(checker & (1 << (s[i] - 'A')))`, or a subset?

Comment: @CodesInChaos I have seen `O(n^2)` implementations, and I was trying for a faster approach, so yes.

Comment: @NiekHaarman Using a HashSet to store which character we've seen before shouldn't change the time complexity since both `add` and `contains` are constant time. In practice it would indeed be a bit slower. 

Using something like `boolean[] charOccurred = new boolean[256];` to store whether one of 256 characters has already occurred should also have the same complexity and when I quickly checked looked like it was even faster (for really large inputs) than the bit logic.

Both approaches should also be easier to extend to larger character set (which is an issue, as @benrudgers pointed out below)

Comment: You're right. I did forget to mention that avoiding an extra buffer was a preference. Also, since the size of a boolean is not defined and [might as well be a byte](http://stackoverflow.com/a/383597/675383), this brings a lot of space overhead. The comparison in speed is interesting, I'll look into that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Caveat:** Unicode has been around for over 25 years. Unicode's 110,000 characters are four orders of magnitude more than the 26 under consideration. In the messy real world, any interesting problem involving character processing is highly likely to bump into it..*

### Data Structures

At scale, the bit by bit data representation is impractical because parsing 110,000 bit integers [or even 256 bit integers representing all of ASCII] is likely to be much harder than the original problem (i.e. implementing consistent 256 bit integer arithmetic is non-trival).

This is not to say that the general problem is overly difficult. To the contrary, it is well understood because it is so common. A common data structure addressing this class of problems is the [Hash Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) because hash tables have constant time [O(1)] lookup. For large ranges of keys, the overhead of implementing a Hash Table is often overwhelmed by the savings in lookup.

### Implementation

Hash Table data structures are available as a robust Java implementation:

- Hash Tables are available directly in Java via [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

A pseudo-code implementation:

```
forEach character in characters
   myHashTable.insert(character, TRUE)

return myHashTable.keys.toArray()
```

### Performance

For special applications an approach such as that described in the question may offer better performance than a generalized approach using HashMap. A possible  alternative in such cases might be [Bloom Filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter). A field tested [Java implementation of Bloom Filters](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/hash/BloomFilter.html) is available via Google's [Guava](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Guava) library.

Comment: You're absolutely right when it comes to unicode, and a Hash Table scales better. What about using a [BitSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html)?

Comment: @NiekHaarman After posting, I thought about that sort of thing. Forgetting about UniCode for a moment and just looking at ASCII inputs, Why not a 256 element `Byte` array, treating the input as Bytes rather than Char, and looping `MyArray[character] = TRUE`? Of course, `BitSet` makes sense for highly constrained memory applications. I pushed my answer up to optimize applicability rather than down toward constraints not listed in the question. Profiling would reveal areas where local optimization matters.